# Where do you get the poke radar

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have beat the league and I need the poke radar to get shinys where is the item located?
are there any other requirements apart form beating the league?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After beating the Pokemon League, go back to the Pokemon Lab in Lumiose City and go to the second floor. Go to the top right corner and talk to a scientist who will give you the radar.

All you need to do is beat the pokemon League.